# How do I select a range of two numpy indices?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, jupyter, slice

I have a simple numpy array, and I want to make a separate array that takes every two elements per two indices

For example:

```
x = np.arange(0,20)

print(x)
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
```

My goal is to get an array of

```
[2 3 6 7 10 11 14 15 18 19]
```

How might I do that? I tried this:

```
print(x[1:len(x)-1:2])

[ 1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17]
```

but I only get every other index.

Comment: You can simply do this using the traditional `start:stop:step` convention without any modulo by reshaping your array, indexing, and then flattening it back. Check my solution for details.

Comment: Reshape `x` to be `[[0,1],[2,3],[4,5],[6,7],...]`.  Then pick every other 'row'.  `x.reshape(-1,2)[::2,:]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do this using the traditional `start:stop:step` convention without any modulo by reshaping your array, indexing, and then flattening it back. Try this -

1. By reshaping it to (-1,2) you create bi-gram sequence
2. Then you simply start from 1 and step 2 times
3. Last you flatten it back.

```
x.reshape(-1,2)[1::2].flatten()
```

```
array([ 2,  3,  6,  7, 10, 11, 14, 15, 18, 19])
```

This should be **significantly faster** than approaches where mathematical operations are being used to check each value since this is just reshaping and indexing.

Comment: This is 4x faster than my `take` solution and 15x faster than the `isin` solution.

Comment: one last question!! thank you! If I had a 3d array with size say (20, 10, 15) but I still wanted to do the same operation but on the first axis (size 20). How would I reshape it? to do the same thing. thanks!

Comment: You can use np.pad and pad it to the nearest 2*n length .. then do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```py
print([x[i] for i in range(len(x)) if not(((i - 2) % 4) and ((i - 3) % 4))])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the modulo `%` to find the latter 2 elements of every group of four:

```
>>> x[np.isin(x % 4, [2,3])]

array([ 2,  3,  6,  7, 10, 11, 14, 15, 18, 19])
```

If your elements aren't a `range` (and thus their value isn't equal to their index), you could take a new `arange`:

```
>>> x = x[::-1] # reverse x
>>> x[np.isin(np.arange(len(x)) % 4, [2,3])]

array([17, 16, 13, 12,  9,  8,  5,  4,  1,  0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this to get these numbers in one line:

```
print([x[i] for i in range(len(x-2)) if (i+2)%4==0 or (i+1)%4==0])
```